# UIAlertview in iphone application

Tags: iphone, uialertview

I am new to iphone application.I am working on my first app.I have to implement alertview with three textfields and three labels(currentpassword,newpassword,verifypassword) and two uibuttons(submit,cancel).Title is:changepassword.upto now,I found only single textfield and two uibutton fields.can anybody tell me,how can i done this?give me a example or detailed explanation.

Comment: The only answer I'm willing to give is: don't. Putting text fields in alert views is against the iOS Human Interface Guidelines. You should create a view controller that has the three fields and buttons that you need and present it modally.

Comment: @Jasarien It might be against the HIG, but Apple does it a lot too, when there's only one, maybe two `UITextField` s to show, and using a seperate view controller would be overkill. Of course if you need >= 2 `UITextField` s, like the OP does, you should just use a view controller.

Comment: Apple also do a large list of other things that they don't permit 3rd party developers to do either. With Apple it's a case of "do as we say, not as we do".

Comment: @Jasarien: Man, you have made a great point regarding Apple's "do as we say, not as we do" policy. I love it..

Comment: @Douwe Maan: Man, your point is also worth considering..

Comment: @Jasarien Of course we should try to follow the HIG (what Apple says), but the HIG's reason for being is to make apps as immediately familiar to users as possible, and what would be better to base your app's Human Interface on than the apps that are already on every user's device (what Apple does)?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot of stuff there. As the commenters note, a modal viewController is the way to go. You can have it slide up from the bottom and cover everything with `setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical`.